# Не ставятся картинки сбоку как на макете. Как это сделать?

Tags: html, css, frontend

```css
body {
    padding: 100px 75px 101px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#2d2d2d;
    font-style: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
}
.header {
    margin: 12px 403px 52px 3px;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 65px;
    font-weight: 700;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

p {
    width: 1092px;
    margin: 0px 73px 30px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.middle-section {
    width: 1088px;
    height: 583px;
    margin: 57px 150px 54px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.text-style {
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
    width: 445px;
    margin: 20px 264px 26px 1px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
}

img {
    width: 1095px;
    height: 560px;
    margin: 52px 143px 57px 0;
}

.advertising-stambul {
    background-image: url('./img/stambul.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-size: auto;
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #fff;
}

.advertising-stambul-title {
    width: 346px;
    height: 67px;
    margin: 0 0 18px 1px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.advertising-stambul-text{
    width: 298px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 18px 49px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.advertising-duster{
    background-image: url('./img/Duster.png');
    background-position: right;
    background-size: auto;
    font-family: Lato;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
}

.advertising-duster-title{
    width: 356px;
    height: 23px;
    margin: 0 0 23px 3px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold
}

.advertising-duster-text{
    width: 334px;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 23px 25px 0 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OnlineShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div>
            <div>
                <h1 class="header">Как ухаживать за обувью из кожи</h1>
                <p>
                    Материала для обуви лучше натуральной кожи все ещё не придумали. Качественную кожу очень приятно носить, 
                    она идеально ложится по ноге, в нужных местах немного растягивается. 
                    В кожаной обуви, если она соответствует погоде, создаётся хороший микроклимат – ноги не мёрзнут, не потеют,
                    и чувствуют себя очень комфортно.
                    Неудивительно, что по статистике больше 60% покупателей выбирает обувь именно из гладкой натуральной кожи. 
                    Вдобавок кожа практична и не требует трудоёмкого ухода. 
                </p>
                <p>
                    Но это совсем не означает, что можно раз в полгода протереть обувь тряпочкой и на этом остановиться. 
                    Так же, как кожа лица и тела, материал обуви нуждается в заботе. 
                    Регулярный уход надолго продлит срок службы любимой пары и сделает
                    её аккуратной и сияющей, словно только что из магазина.
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                        На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Ежедневный уход за кожанной обувью в домашних условиях
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <img  src="./img/shous.jpg"  alt="Замшевые ботинки">
            </div>
            <div class="advertising-stambul">
                <span class="advertising-stambul-title">Горящие туры в Стамбул от 20 000руб</span>
                <span class="advertising-stambul-text" >Окунись в настоящую восточную сказку</span>
            </div>
            <div class="advertising-duster">
                <span class="advertising-duster-title"> Новый Renault Duster</span>
                <span class="advertising-duster-text">Легендарный внедорожник в новом дизайне</span>
            </div>
            <div class="middle-section">
                <span class="text-style">На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой</span>
                <p>
                    Подбирайте обувь точно по размеру и полноте. 
                    Слишкам тесная обувь черезмерно растягивается 
                    и кожа испортится,не говоря уже о дискомфорте. 
                    А если модель сидит слишком свободно, то при ходьбе 
                    на ней начнут образовываться складки и заломы.
                </p>
                <span  class="text-style">Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз</span>
                <p>
                    Перед первой ноской для новой пары нужно подобрать водо- или грязеоттакивающее средство,
                    подхлдящее для натуральной кожи, и обработать кожу в соответсвии с инструкцией. 
                    После высыхания - чистить кремом.
                </p>
                <span class="text-style">Ежедневный уход за кожаной обувью в домашних условиях</span>
                <p>
                    Лучше всего заняться обувью после возвращения домой. 
                    Если этого не сделать, то со временем появляются трудновыводимые пятна,
                    портится цвет кожи, образуются трещены.
                </p>
                <p>
                    После каждого выхода на улицу протирайте обувь сухой салфеткой,
                    если на коже только пыль, или вложной тряпкой - в случае сильного
                    загрязнения. Начинайте мыть с каблука, затем очистите подошву,после
                    этого - материал верха. После мытья нужно как следует протереть пару мягкой тканью,
                    чтобы избавить от лишней влаги. Иначе обувь будетсушиться очень долго.
                </p>
                </div>
                <div>
                <img src="./img/brush.jpg" alt="средства для чистки обуви">
                <p>
                    Второй этап-сушка.
                    Ни в коем случае не используйте источники тепла - батарею, 
                    обогреватель, фен с горячим воздухом. 
                    Да,они сушат быстро, но за это приходит расплата в виде
                    задубевшей покоробившейся кожи. Нужно вытащить стельки,
                    набить обувь бумагой либо положить внутрь формодержатель
                    и сушить при комнатной температуре. Тогда ваши туфли или сапоги 
                    надолго сохранят красивую форму
                    без заломов. сушка дляться довольно долго, и по этому не 
                    рекомендуется носить одну и ту же пару каждый день. 
                    Обувь и подкладка должны отдохнуть и расправиться, только тогда вам будет комфортно и тепло.
                </p>
                <p>
                    И наконец-крем.
                    Сухую и чистую пару нужно обработать кремом, чтобы кожа оставалась 
                    эластичной,мягкой и блестящей. Наносите крем тоненьким слоем с помощью
                    обувной щетки и аккуратно распределите по всейповерхности
                    Затем через несколько часов, когда крем впитается, сотрите остатки сухой салфеткой
                    отпалируйте кожу мягкой тряпочкой.
                    Крем подбирается точно в цвет обуви, поэтому стоит задуматься
                    еще перед покупкой, каким уходовым средством вы будете пользоваться.<br>
                    В магазине легко подобрать черный, коричневый и самый универсальный-
                    бесцветный крем, есть и другие цвета, где бывает сложно найти нужный оттенок.<br>
                    По мере необходимости дополнительно обрабатывайте пару водотталкивающими спреями
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Они должны быть не в тексте, а отдельным блоком - [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/nD5j4BM.png)

Answer (score 1):

создаете общий контейнер, например `wrapper`, внутри создаете два блока, отдельный блок для контента с тектом, отдельный блок для боковых картинок, и потом задаете `display: flex;` для общего контейнера

```css
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>OnlineShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-item">
                <h1 class="header">Как ухаживать за обувью из кожи</h1>
                <p>
                    Материала для обуви лучше натуральной кожи все ещё не придумали. Качественную кожу очень приятно носить,
                    она идеально ложится по ноге, в нужных местах немного растягивается.
                    В кожаной обуви, если она соответствует погоде, создаётся хороший микроклимат – ноги не мёрзнут, не потеют,
                    и чувствуют себя очень комфортно.
                    Неудивительно, что по статистике больше 60% покупателей выбирает обувь именно из гладкой натуральной кожи.
                    Вдобавок кожа практична и не требует трудоёмкого ухода.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Но это совсем не означает, что можно раз в полгода протереть обувь тряпочкой и на этом остановиться.
                    Так же, как кожа лица и тела, материал обуви нуждается в заботе.
                    Регулярный уход надолго продлит срок службы любимой пары и сделает
                    её аккуратной и сияющей, словно только что из магазина.
                </p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        На что стоит обратить внимание перед покупкой
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Перед тем, как надеть обувь в превый раз
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Ежедневный уход за кожанной обувью в домашних условиях
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="advertising">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x160/777" alt="">
                <div class="advertising-text">
                    <span class="advertising-title">Горящие туры в Стамбул от 20 000руб</span>
                    <span class="advertising-subtitle" >Окунись в настоящую восточную сказку</span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="advertising">
                <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/300x160/999" alt="">
                <div class="advertising-text">
                    <span class="advertising-title">Новый Renault Duster</span>
                    <span class="advertising-subtitle">Легендарный внедорожник в новом дизайне</span>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```